# Facebook log in dialog mistakenly suggests that my app is asking for some sort of publish permission

Tags: ios, facebook, permissions

My application asks for the email permission only:

```
NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"email", nil];
[self.facebook authorize:permissions];
```

However, when the user is prompted to log in, the dialog says that my app can post on their behalf:

[image: dialog]

Am I missing something?

(UPDATE) Looks like I'm not alone. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/273948536030203

Comment: I've confirmed that I get this behavior with the code above running against a brand new FB app that has absolutely no options set - i.e. default settings only - no open graph actions, objects or profile units, no authenticated referrals, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you accidentally (or not accidentally but don't remember) enabled the [Authenticated Referrals](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/authentication/#referrals) in the Auth Dialog settings?

It happened to us once and took a while to figure out why the permissions we ask for are completely ignored.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, that's not my problem. Authenticated Referrals is not set for my app.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that's not the `publish_actions` description? The two permissions have similar descriptions, and publish_actions is implicit if your app publishes Open Graph actions or games Achievements or Scores

Comment: Another great suggestion. Thanks. I've updated the title since I guess I'm not certain it was publish_stream.

My app isn't an open graph app, so I don't think I should need publish_actions implicitly.

Comment: That icon is the one for publish_actions as far as I know; have you got any open graph configuration in your app? even if you're not actively publishing actions it may be triggering that in the auth dialog